# How can I graph a 2-dimensional plane in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I wish to graph this image. I am kind of new on LaTex and tikz, and can't really get my way round this. I hope someone comes to my aid.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\set[1]{\{#1\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
  \draw[->] % x axis
    (-2,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$\mathbb{R}\times\set{0}$};
  \draw[->] % y axis
    (0,-1) -- (0,3) node[above]{$\set{0}\times\mathbb{R}$};
  \draw % ticks
    (1,-0.1) node[below]{$(1,0)$} -- +(0,0.2) % relative coordinate, added to (1,-0.1)
    (-0.1,1) node[left]{$i=(0,1)$} -- + (0.2,0);  relative coordinate, added to (-0.1,1)
  \draw[dashed] % dashed lines 
    (2.5,0) node[below]{$(x,0)$} --
    (2.5,2.5) node{$\bullet$} node[above right]{$(x,y)$} --
    (0,2.5) node[left]{$(0,y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```